# Data transfer between Android activities

Tags: java, arrays, vector

> Hello everyone, I want to pass numbers from activity A to activity B, someone knows how to make?. My ID is java (Android developer tools).

My code!

Activity A

```
double[] decimal = {1,2,3,4};
Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(A.this, B.class);
mainIntent.putExtra("decimal", decimal);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

Activity B

```
double[] decimal1 = new double[3];
decimal= getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra("decimal");
System.out.printil(decimal1);
```

My error is at the time of printing

```
D@65257c8
```

My reference

http://strefakodera.pl/programowanie/android-java/przesylanie-danych-miedzy-aktywnosciami-w-androidzie

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(decimal1));`

Comment: Excellent contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the array object, so the JVM will print the hash of that array. If you want to print the double numbers inside the array you have to cycle on it:

replace this:

```
System.out.printil(decimal1);
```

with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < decimal.lenght; i++)
    System.out.println("A number: " + decimal[i])
```

Comment: Excellent contribution
Thank you